# Perl Cleartool Accept Statement

Tags: perl, cleartool

I am using the following code to execute the ClearCase statement "Accept" from a perl script.

```
$acceptA = `accept $Component`;
```

After execution, inside my perl script,  the value of `$acceptA` is blank.

The text displayed on the screen during execution of this line is : "ERROR You do not have permissions to ACCEPT this work."

How do I read this line? I thought it would return into the variable `$acceptA` as it does with the "cleartool checkin" command?

Comment: `accept $Component` is inside "back ticks" although not visible above...

Comment: I am not aware of ant 'accept' ClearCase UCM command. Is that a CC-ClearQuest workflow command? And RTC one?

Comment: Yes, it is a workflow tool on Unix. The accept command works. It is used by the team leader after a program has been checked in to accept the changes...

Comment: So is it possible that your script isn't executed by the right user? (meaning, by a user with enough privilege to use the `accept` command)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, however I'd like to read the error into the script so that I can write a proper error message to a log file...

Comment: So DeVadder's answer should help then, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes his answer definately helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i do not know ClearCase and how that accept works, i can only guess. Seeing how it is an error message, it might be written to STDERR instead of STDOUT and backticks only capture STDOUT of the command executed.
In that case, redirecting the commands STDERR to STDOUT would work. Try

```
$acceptA = `accept $Component 2>&1`
```

and see if that works in capturing the output in case of error as well.

Comment: I'm still not able to process the error with the above, but I think you're right about writing to STDERR... Going to play around with this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually redirected SYSERR to an output file which I could read/write.

open STDERR, ">/ellipse/el6.3.3_ry_sup/src/0/$logfile"

All the error messages that was displayed on the screen as part of the system command, went into $logfile.

I was also able to add to SYSERR with the following:
print STDERR "\nAccepting $Component";

Thanks for all the help.